# Для чего нужны Header файлы в С++? Почему нельзя писать без них?

Tags: c++, header, компиляция

Весь гугл перерыл, не могу понять. И википедию перечитал и вообще все что угодно перечитал. Правда не понимаю.

Что мешает подключать просто .cpp файлы?

Ну подключил ты его два раза, ну пусть компилятор только один раз подключает и все, раз он один черт все в один как бы файл склеивает, значит первое подключение будет выше остальных и будет видно им внизу. Пусть смотрит время изменения и перекомпилирует только изменившееся. Пусть автоматически генерирует и прикрепляет header файлы с описанием интерфейсов к откомпилированному бинарнику и т.п.

Иными словами, почему рутиная работа по генерации хедер файлов, не автоматизирована и возложена на разработчика? Ведь компилятор рядом с откомпилированным бинарником может легко сам сгенерировать файл описания интерфейсов (который он получил, сканируя cpp файл).

Можете привести ситуацию, в которой бы возникали ПРОБЛЕМЫ без использования хедер файлов? Это будет самое лучшее обьяснение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53067/discussion-on-question-by-maxmaxmaximus----header----).

Comment: Наверно уже сказали, но на всякий случай:
Потому что можно писать без .h и можно просто включать .cpp Просто ты не понимаешь разницу между двумя подходами и не понимаешь поэтому, зачем это нужно - использовать заголовочные файлы.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Проблема лежит в области обратной совместимости.

Посмотрите, любой новый язык программирования — да даже Паскаль, не говоря уже о Java или C# — не нуждаются в заголовочных файлах. Без сомнения, C++ тоже мог бы обойтись без них. В чём же дело?

Перенесёмся на полвека назад, в 1972 год. Представим себе компилятор языка C.

Допустим, мы хотим написать дизайн компилятора. Мы не можем скомпилировать **всю** программу за раз, у нас на это просто не хватит памяти. Компьютеры тогда были маленькими и медленными. Мы хотим компилировать программу по кусочкам, по нескольку функций за раз.

У нас сразу же возникает проблема: как скомпилировать функцию `f`, которая ссылается на другую функцию `g`? Нам нужно отдельное *описание* других функций. Мы могли бы, конечно, прочитать все исходные файлы, для начала выяснить, какие функции у нас есть, и затем прочитать их *второй раз* и скомпилировать один за одним. Но это было слишком сложно и медленно, нужно было парсить определения функций дважды, и один раз выбрасывать результат! Это недопустимый расход процессорного времени! Плюс если держать в памяти определения **всех** функций, может снова-таки не хватить памяти.

На кого [Деннис](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) решил возложить сложную проблему отделения описания функции от её реализации, и подключения только нужных описаний при компиляции данной функции? На нас, программистов. Он решил, что мы должны сами помочь компилятору и скопипастить определения функций в отдельный файл, и сами указать компилятору, какие файлы с определениями нужны. (То есть первый шаг компиляции возлагается на нас.)

Это радикально упростило компилятор, но привело в свою очередь к проблемам. Что будет, если мы забыли подключить нужный заголовочный файл? Ответ: ошибка компиляции. Что будет, если смысл текста заголовочного файла меняется в зависимости от какого-нибудь макроса? Ответ: компилятор «тупой», и не пытается детектировать эту проблему, он перекладывает ответственность на нас.

На момент разработки языка это было правильное решение. Компилятор оказался практичным, быстрым, и программисты были не прочь помочь компиляции. Ну и если кто допускал ошибку, сам был виноват.

Перемотаем стрелки часов в 1983 год. [Бьярн](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) создаёт C++. Он решил взлететь на волне популярности языка C, и перенял модель компиляции C с отдельными translation unit'ами и связанными с этим проблемами прямо из C. Впрочем, первые версии C++ были просто препроцесоором языка C! Поэтому проблемы раздельной компиляции перекочевали из C в C++. Хуже того, добавились новые проблемы. Например, шаблоны классов выглядят как классы, но не генерируют объектного кода сами по себе, поэтому для них приходится идти на ухищрения и обходить недостатки системы раздельной компиляции (например, включением реализации в header и трюками компоновщика).

А дальше вступила в игру обратная совместимость. Сейчас, в 2017 году, есть так много кода, написанного в стиле «с заголовками», и так много кода исходит из различных тонкостей, связанных с этим, что менять парадигму уже поздно, поезд практически уехал.

Впрочем, существует проект модульной системы в C++, который должен помочь программистам избавиться от наследства полувековой давности. Он ещё не реализован, и в нём есть сложности уровня дизайна (например, в header'е был определён макрос, будет ли он виден, если мы перейдём от header'ов к модулям?) Надеюсь, в будущем разработчики языка таки смогут побороть проблему обратной совместимости.

Comment: А разве Си не унаследовал заголовочники от ассемблера?

Comment: @Cerbo: Хм. Я об этом не слыхал. А что, в ассемблере есть заголовочные файлы? о_О Макроассемблеры — штука довольно новая, если вы о них.

Comment: @VladD, а чего никто не вспоминает, что я могу намеренно подключать cpp-файл несколько раз? Неужели никто так не делает?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, потому что это не intended use, а скорее abuse системы инклюдов. Хотя да, в C++ по традиции для любого бага определения находился кто-то, кто начинал его использовать, и баг превращался в фичу. Пример — SFINAE :-P

Comment: @VladD, это про 90% использования шаблонов можно сказать, что не intended use :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Истина!

Comment: Читал ответ как главу детективного романа. Прекрасный ответ :)

Comment: @isnullxbh: Спасибо! :)

Comment: мужик, ты шикарен

Answer (score 10):

Сборка программы происходит в три этапа: препроцессор, компилятор и компоновщик.

Препроцессор, обрабатывая директиву `#include "file"`, подставит **содержимое** `file` в текущий файл.

Получается, если вы включите cpp файл в несколько компилируемых файлов, то он будет скомпилирован несколько раз. И вот тут вступает в силу [Правило одного определения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Заодно, почитайте, что такое [Единица трансляции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Приведу пример:

ClassA.cpp

```
class ClassA {
public:
    void someFunction() {};
}
```

ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.cpp"
class ClassB {
}
```

ClassC.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.cpp"
class ClassC {
}
```

После выполнения препроцессора у вас ClassB.cpp и ClassC.cpp соответственно превратятся в

```
class ClassA {
public:
    void someFunction() {};
}
class ClassB {
}
```

и

```
class ClassA {
public:
    void someFunction() {};
}
class ClassC {
}
```

И только теперь начинается компиляция. Даже если вы не будете отдельно компилировать ClassA.cpp, то все равно нарушите правило одного определения (ClassA определен в двух единицах трансляции - ClassB.cpp и ClassC.cpp).

Comment: 1) мы указываем компилятору набор cpp файлов
2) в одних подключаем другие с помощью #include "file.cpp"
3) если подключение файла дублируется он его не подключает второй раз
4) если мы компилируем по отдельности, то вместе с откомпиированным бинарником должен АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ создаваться хедер файл содержащий ВЫДРАННОЕ  ОПИСАНИЕ ИНТЕРФЕЙСОВ из cpp файла с кодом. 5) почему создатели компилятора так не сделали? почему заставляют руками хедеры генерировать?

Comment: Иными словами почему рутиная работа по генерации хедер файлов, не автоматизированна и возложенна на разработчика? Ведь компилятор рядом с откомпилированным бинарником может легко сам сгенерировать файл описания интерфейсов (который он получил сканируя cpp файл)

Comment: Если я инклюдю уже откомпилированный cpp файл то компилятор должен смотреть время изменения и понимать что перекомпилировать файл уже не нужно. Почему это не сделано? Можете обьяснить? Я хочу понять одно, это глупость разработчиков языка, или необходимость которую я не понимаю)?

Comment: Еще раз прочитайте про единицу трансляции. Когда компилируется cpp файл, компилятор не знает ничего о других cpp файлах (был ли он уже откомпилирован). 

По поводу "рутинной работы по генерации хедер файлов". Обычно при написании программ сначала думают об интерфейсе (пишут .h), а потом только пишут реализацию (.cpp)

Comment: "Когда компилируется cpp файл, компилятор не знает ничего о других cpp файлах" знает! он может посмотреть в свою папку tmp файлов и поискать там его бинарник по имени, если хэш сумма совпадает значит перекомпилировать не нужно.

Comment: "Обычно при написании программ сначала думают об интерфейсе" в cpp файле ты описываешь интерфейс, например метода, когда описываешь его параметры. ни кто не мешает тебе придумывать класс оставляя тела методов пустыми и задавая только параметры. а потом уже начать его наполнять.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus А что, если например я не хочу, чтобы все мои функции из cpp были автоматически выставлены наружу в header, как вы предлагаете.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus Не знает о других cpp из-за препроцессора. Я привел пример в ответе.

Comment: @Krepver хммм. почему бы при подключении cpp файла, ему бы НЕ вставлять его ТУПО как текст, а генерировать на его основе как бы виртуальный header файл и вставлять УЖЕ ЕГО как текст? Приведите пример пожалуйста когда человек хочет чтобы в хедер файле НЕ объявлялась какая то штука из cpp файла? Ну то есть что плохого если на всякий случай ВСЕ обьявятся?)

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста когда человек хочет чтобы в хедер файле НЕ объявлялась какая то штука из cpp файла?

Такое часто встречается - какая-то вспомогательная структура, константа, которая нужна только тут и наружу смотреть не должна, и тому подобное.

Comment: @isnullxbh почему не ввести ключевые слова импорт експорт?

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду? Не совсем Вас понял.

Comment: @snullxbh почему в cpp файле не показывать что импортировать а что приватным внутренним оставлять? почему не ввести доп слова типа екстерн импорт експорт и.т.п?

Answer (score 10):

Так сложилось исторически. Использование автоматически сгенерированных заголовочных файлов требует непростой сборочной системы, которая бы умела определять порядок компиляции при наличии сложных зависимостей между модулями.

А поскольку на момент становления языка таких систем еще не придумали - то добавлять генерацию заголовочного файла в компиляторы не стали. И до сих пор такой системы не появилось потому что компиляторы не умеют генерировать заголовочные файлы.

Возможно, модули из нового стандарта все изменят.

---

В любом случае, заголовочные файлы останутся для тех случаев, когда импорт .cpp-файла неприменим ни в каком виде. Например, когда .cpp-файла и нет - при подключении сторонней библиотеки. Или при наличии циклической зависимости между модулями. Или просто в ситуации, когда на заголовочный файл налагаются дополнительные требования, делающие его автоматическую генерацию недопустимой.

Comment: Кстати, насколько я знаю, стандарт *не требует* наличия в компиляторе этих заголовочных файлов именно в виде файлов... Т.е. теоретически возможна реализация, у которой не будет *реальных* заголовочных файлов стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @Harry это из серии *"стандарт не требует наличия компилятора, достаточно программы, выполняющей ту же самую функцию"* :)

Comment: @Harry в любом случае, с библиотеками, отличными от стандартной, такие фокусы уже не пройдут.

Answer (score 9):

Ожидается что в C++17 появится первый стандартизировнный вариант модулей, то есть поддержки сборок без заголовочных файлов. Насколько я понял в этом варианте модули будут реализованы как расширение компилятора, то есть это фнукция будет необязательной в C++17.

Однако уже сейчас модули реализованы в [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/) и [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html), так что их можно попробовать.

Answer (score 7):

> Что мешает подключать просто .cpp файлы?

Отсутствие в них информации о типах, доступной извне.

Компилятор превращает файлы исходных кодов (`.c` и `.cpp`) в *объектные файлы* (`.obj`, сшиваемые позднее компоновщиком в единый `.exe` или `.dll` файл) — «полуфабрикаты»-«чёрные ящики», импортирующие и экспортирующие *символы*.

Символ, в свою очередь, — это совокупность «имя функции/переменной — её смещение относительно начала объектного файла». Импорт — это зависимости объектного файла (при этом неважно, где они будут реализованы, требуется лишь совпадение имён); экспорт — это то, что в этом файле реализовано.

Таким образом, объектные файлы **не содержат типов данных** и прочих абстракций, существующих исключительно в воображении компилятора. Только машинный код и данные, существующие в виде реально выделяемого места в ОЗУ, и именованные метки.

К сожалению, одного только знания имени недостаточно для формирования импорта (зависимости). Компилятору необходимо знать ещё структуру принимающих участие типов для генерации корректных смещений на стеке, вставки дополнительных вызовов конструкторов/деструкторов, выполнения неявных преобразований типов, проверки корректности вызова и т. д.

Так как этой информации в объектном файле нет (напомню, там только имена), она должна быть описана в виде объявлений в том файле исходных кодов, который эту внешнюю сущность хочет использовать. Описание можно выполнить либо в самом `.cpp` файле, либо вынести его в отдельный `.hpp` файл и подключать его всюду, где требуется описание типа.

Почему же описание типов не встраивается в реализующий их объектный файл? Один и тот же тип данных может использоваться в произвольном количестве мест, а потому подобное встраивание нарушает *правило одного определения*. Согласно этому правилу всякая сущность должна иметь только один источник (объектный файл), чтобы у компоновщика не было неопределённости при сопоставлении импортов и экспортов.

> Ну пусть компилятор только один раз подключает и все, раз он один черт все в один как бы файл все склеивает, значит первое подключение будет выше остальных и будет видно им внизу.

Сборка программы на *C* и *C++* происходит в два этапа.

1. Компилятор превращает каждый файл исходных кодов (`.c` и `.cpp`) в *объектный файл* (`.obj`). При этом каждый файл исходных кодов компилируется независимо, будто он один во вселенной и никого кроме него больше не существует. **На этом этапе компилятор не видит других объектных файлов**, но он *уже* обязан выдать готовый машинный код. Такой подход был выбран разработчиками языка для возможности распараллеливания компиляции.
2. Компоновщик берёт указанные объектные файлы (неважно, как и когда они были получены), связывает их импорты и экспорты и объединяет в единый исполняемый (`.exe` или `.dll`) файл.

> Иными словами почему рутиная работа по генерации хедер файлов, не автоматизированна и возложенна на разработчика? Ведь компилятор рядом с откомпилированным бинарником может легко сам сгенерировать файл описания интерфейсов (который он получил сканируя cpp файл).

Вот вам `.cpp` файл (без включения нестандартных заголовков, как хотели):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

Logger::Logger()
    : _console(std::cout)
{
}

void Logger::log(const std::string& message)
{
    _console << message;
}
```

Как компилятор выведет из этого структуру класса `Logger`? А именно: какие поля должны быть в классе и каков их модификатор доступа? Ведь реализация одного класса может быть распределена по нескольким файлам, ровно как и один файл может содержать реализацию части методов нескольких классов.

Вы, наверное, скажете: «описать `class Logger{...};` здесь же, чтобы из него генерировался `.hpp`». А в чём тогда разница, если мы это описание и так выносим в заголовочный файл?

> Можете привести ситуацию в которой бы возникали ПРОБЛЕМЫ без использования хедер файлов?

- *myclass.cpp*

  ```
  #include <cstdlib>

  class Foo
  {
      int _value;

  public:
      Foo()
          : _value(rand())
      {
      }

      // ... ещё много-много методов

      int bar() const
      {
          return _value;
      }
  }
  ```
- *main.cpp*

  ```
  // Копия простыни из foo.cpp
  #include <iostream>

  class Foo
  {
      int _value;

  public:
      Foo();

      // ... ещё много-много методов

      int bar() const;
  }

  int main()
  {
      Foo a;
      std::cout << a.bar();
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *one-more-file.cpp*

  ```
  // Ещё раз копия
  class Foo
  {
      int _value;

  public:
      Foo();

      // ... ещё много-много методов

      int bar() const;
  }

  // ...
  ```
- ну и так далее для каждого файла, использующего `Foo`.

А теперь представьте, что каждое изменение описания класса потребует массовой замены *в большом количестве мест*. Забудете исправить — компилятор промолчит, будучи введённый в заблуждение, на итоговая программа будет падать.

Comment: "// Запрещаем копирование и перемещение, объявив хотя бы один конструктор вручную". Разве это запрещает? http://ideone.com/7RlHhH. По-моему в таком случае только конструктор по умолчанию не определяется.

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибка вышла. Вы абсолютно правы. Исправил.

Answer (score 5):

> Ну подключил ты его два раза, ну пусть компилятор только один раз подключает и все

А если я не хочу один раз?

Вот предположим, я генерирую за счёт макросов пачку похожих функций, где какие-то минимальные различия в поведении определяются другими макросами. Т. о. вместо генерации кода я меняю значения констант и подключаю один и тот же cpp-файл в другой cpp-файл. А ты хочешь меня этой возможности лишить?

Вот пример: http://ideone.com/TlN4r0. Хотя есть лишние усложнения из-за того, что приходится всё в один файл упихивать (ради ideone), но идея должна быть понятна. А ещё, предполагается, что функция достаточно большая, но различия достаточно маленькие. В таком случае помещение всей функции в макрос становится нерациональным.

```
#ifndef MAIN

#define MAIN 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define D 1
#include __FILE__
#undef D

#define D 2
#include __FILE__
#undef D

int main()
{
    cout << add1(10) << ' ' << add2(10) << endl;
    return 0;
}

#else

#define ADD0(d) add##d
#define ADD(d) ADD0(d)

int ADD(D)(int x)
{
    return x + D;
}

#undef ADD0
#undef ADD

#endif
```

Comment: А ты хочешь меня этой возможности лишить? - Нет я не хочу тебя этой возморжности лишать, после прохода препроцессора компилятор смотрит изменился ли файл или нет, если изменился, то делает вклейку второй раз.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, интересный вариант. Но мне он кажется достаточно затратным - дерево зависимостей и глубина вложенности может быть очень большой - получится неоправданная многократная проверка одних и тех же файлов. Наверное.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus: О какой "вклейке второй раз" идет речь и "вклейке" чего вообще, если вы предлагаете устранить заголовочные файлы полностью?

Comment: @Qwertiy получится неоправданная многократная проверка одних и тех же файлов. - Нет, так щас другие языки делают и это наносекундная операция. Просто лежит мап файл, которй сгенерирован при первой полной компиляции, в котором описаны все версии файлов и их соответствие друг другу и все такое прочее. И все) Компилятору не придется физически пробегаться по всем файлам и сканировать, он просто загрузит меп файл в оперативку и от туда всю инфу узнает. Ну то есть такие вещи как раз легко легко кэшируются, и именно так устроенны компиляторы других языков.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, в других языках нет возможности многократно подключить один файл. Т. е. он один раз распарсился, и больше не пересчитывается. В таком случае - да, накладных расходов на это мало. Но если мы всё же можем так делать, а критерием повторного включения будет наличие изменений в скомпилированной версии, то придётся каждый раз его обрабатывать, а потом смотреть, поменялось что-то или нет. Потому что изменения могут быть спровоцированы появлением любых define'ов, а может и подключением файлов с другими определениями функций.

Comment: @Qwertiy чтобы посмотреть изменился ли файл достаточно посмотреть его атрибут время последнего изменения, и сравнить. Эта операция в миллиард раз дешевле прочитки содержимого header файлов

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, в приведённом в ответе коде один и тот же файл подключается трижды (собственно, один раз просто сам файл и дважды `#include __FILE__`). Он ни разу не меняется, но все 3 раза компиляция приводит к разному результату. При чём тут вообще время последнего изменения?