# Зачем нужны прототипы функций? Зачем нужно обьявление переменных?

Tags: c++, функции, переменные, инициализация

**Зачем нужны прототипы функций? Зачем нужно обьявление переменных?** Почему нельзя без прототипа сразу обьявить функцию с описанием, почему нельзя сразу инициализировать переменные?

```
    int sum(int, int);          //прототип функции с двумя параметрами
void foo();                 //прототип функции без параметров
void foo(const char*);      //прототип функции с одним параметром

int main(){
    foo("HELLO!");          //Использование одной функции
    cout << '\n';
    foo();                  //Использование другой функции
    cout << '\n';
    cout << sum(10,35) <<  "\n=======================\n";       
    cin.get();

}


 // я так понимаю это ОПИСАНИЕ??
    int sum(int x, int y) {                             

        cout << "int sum(int x, int y)\n";
        return 0;
    }

    void foo(){
        cout << "=======================\n";            
        cout << "void foo()";
        cout << "\n=======================\n";
    }

    void foo(const char* S){                            
        cout << "=======================\n";
        cout << "void foo(const char* S)" << endl;
        cout << S;
        cout << "\n=======================\n";
    }
```

Можно ли обойтись без Прототипа?

Comment: В общем случае, можно и можно. Приведите примеры, с которыми у вас возникают описываемые вами проблемы.

Comment: @D-side Да просто стало любопытно, можно ли. Проблем пока нет. А не подскажешь чем прототип отличается от описания функции?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "описанием"? Тело/реализацию?

Comment: @D-side    я понимаю под описанием тело

Comment: А кто сказал, что нельзя?..

Comment: Если вы хотите добавить пример того, о чём спрашиваете, добавляйте лучше сразу в вопрос. Его можно (и часто нужно) редактировать. Предполагайте что комментарии могут испариться в любой момент (это правда так).

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621082/10105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Прототип стал необходим после того, как стандарты языка С изменились таким образом, что перед вызовом функции в файле необходимо каким либо образом ее описать. Проблема состоит в том, что имя функции имеет глобальную область видимости (если ее описание находится вне всяких локальных областей). Допустим, что описание функции находится в отдельном исходном файле. Также допустим, что необходимо осуществить вызов этой же функции в нескольких других исходных файлах. Если нет прототипа, то в каждый такой исходный файл необходимо включить полное описание функции. Компилятор будет интерпретировать это как переопределение. Если же мы используем прототип, то мы можем включать этот прототип в столько исходных файлов, сколько нам необходимо."

http://cppstudio.com/post/404/